# Problem with adding my class into XamlPage

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, oop, .net-4.8

Have a little problem with connecting my class to xamlpage... VS text me that program can't see namespace
[image: like this]

but i have another class at this folder which one is working normaly

[image: this is the structure of my project]

and i want to show you a block of code of xaml page

```
<Page x:Class="ClinicApp.XamlPages.ListOfPatientsPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ClinicApp.XamlPages"
      xmlns:localModels="clr-namespace:ClinicApp.EntityModels" 
      xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:ClinicApp.HelperClasses"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" Width="1200"
      Title="ListOfPatientsPage" Loaded="Page_Loaded" x:Name="page" Background="White">
    <Page.Resources>
        <local:EnumDescriptionConverter x:Key="EnumDescriptionConverter"/>
        <local:AgeConverter x:Key="AgeConverter" />
    </Page.Resources>
```

this one is not working and shows error
`local:AgeConverter x:Key="AgeConverter"` this error is at the beginning of the question

also i can show you working class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ClinicApp.EntityModels;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Reflection;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ClinicApp.XamlPages
{
    //takes descriprion from gender and requestType enums and place is in datagrid
    //instead of showing the real values 
    public class EnumDescriptionConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        private string GetEnumDescription(Enum enumObj)
        {
            FieldInfo fieldInfo = enumObj.GetType().GetField(enumObj.ToString());

            object[] attribArray = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(false);

            if (attribArray.Length == 0)
            {
                return enumObj.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                DescriptionAttribute attrib = attribArray[0] as DescriptionAttribute;
                return attrib.Description;
            }
        }

        object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Enum myEnum = (Enum)value;
            string description = GetEnumDescription(myEnum);
            return description;
        }

        object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

I can't understand why he complains about namespaces
Sorry if this question is stupid... I am just trying to understand wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file EnumDescriptionConverter.cs you probably made a mistake in the namespace (it is `ClinicApp.XamlPages` instead of `ClinicApp.HelperClasses`).
local is defined as `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ClinicApp.XamlPages"` so it works.
I am guessing that AgeConverter is in another namespace (`ClinicApp.HelperClasses`) so it shoul be used like this : `<local1:AgeConverter x:Key="AgeConverter" />`

Just fix the namespace in EnumDescriptionConverter.cs and use local1 (you should probably rename it as helperClasses) and it should work.